# Pinescript: How to only label candle if at least 5 previous candles have not touched the EMA

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have the following code currently:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

ema_val = ta.ema(close, 9)
ema_touch = (ema_val <= high) and (ema_val >= low)

plot(ema_val)
plotshape(ema_touch,style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
```

I want it to only label the candle if at least 5 previous candles have not touched the exponential moving average (EMA)

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ta.barssince()` function for get the number of bars since last touch.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

ema_val = ta.ema(close, 9)
ema_touch = (ema_val <= high) and (ema_val >= low)

bars = ta.barssince(ema_touch)

plot(ema_val)
plotshape(bars==5,style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ema_val = ta.ema(close, 9)
ema_touch = (high <= ema_val) or low>= ema_val

// Custom consecutive bars count  
ConsecBars = input(5, title="Consecutive  Bars")

var count = 0

count := ema_touch ? count + 1 : 0

signal = count >= ConsecBars ? 1 : 0

plot(ema_val)
plotshape(signal and signal!=signal[1], style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
```